# How to extract certain elements from a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a lot of files and I have saved all filenames to `filelists.txt`. Here is an example file:

```
cpu_H1_M1_S1.out  
cpu_H1_M1_S2.out  
cpu_H2_M1_S1.out  
cpu_H2_M1_S2.out
```

When the program detects `_H`, `_M`, `_S` in the file name. I need to output the numbers that appear afterwards. For example:

```
_H     _M     _S  
1       1      1  
1       1      2  
2       1      1  
2       1      2
```

Thank you.

Comment: What range of numbers do you want to choose from, for H, M and S? Also, your question is ambiguous. Please post what you've tried so we can figure out what you're trying to do

Comment: Do all filenames have all of `_H`, `_M`, `_S`? What if something is missing?

Comment: Those numbers are the parameters used in the WEKA.
I want those numbers to create a report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this using `regex`:

```
In [13]: with open("filelists.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        data=re.findall(r"_H\d+_M\d+_S\d+",line)
        if data:
            print [x.strip("HMS") for x in data[0].split("_")[1:]]
   ....:             
['1', '1', '1']
['1', '1', '2']
['2', '1', '1']
['2', '1', '2']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regexp:

```
>>> s = 'cpu_H2_M1_S2.out'
>>> re.findall(r'cpu_H(\d+)_M(\d+)_S(\d+)', s)
[('2', '1', '2')]
```

If it doesn't match the format exactly, you'll get an empty list as a result, which can be used to ignore the results. You could adapt this to convert the str's to int's if you wished:

```
[int(i) for i in re.findall(...)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I have nothing against regex itself, I think it's overkill for this problem. Here's a lighter solution:

```
five = operator.itemgetter(5)
seven = operator.itemgetter(7)
nine = operator.itemgetter(9)
with open("filelists.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        return [(int(five(line)), int(seven(line)), int(nine(nine))) for line in f]
```

Hope that helps